Approximate timeline for annals of maths journal?
For those who have published in the Annals of Mathematics, since there is no editorial manager, how long should one wait before emailing the editor?
Additionally, after how much time can one expect the manuscript to pass the editorial check and be sent out for review?

There are many other questions on this forum about when to email editors. The same guidance applies here.

I do think Annals of Mathematics is a BIT of a special case, as maybe the most selective journal in the subject where journals move the slowest. Since the nuances of the answer may be slightly unique, I'll go ahead and answer, but the mods should obviously feel free to delete the question if it's not deemed on-topic.

Relevant answers/threads: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/32769/17254 https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/122621/17254 https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/13604/17254

Fun tangent exercise: What is the probability that anyone here has something published in the Annals? Critically low, I presume.

@user1149748 Sure, but we can't have a question for the "most selective journal" in every subject, can we?

@user176372, ha! Yes, low probability, but some people who do care about giving good advice really do have the experience to back it up. :) For me, for what it's worth, a paper in the Annals, 2 in Inv. Math., 2 in Duke, 3 in Amer J., etc, ... maybe in easier, happier old times... :) I think quite a few people here really do have experience relevant to such questions... especially "older" people who still do have interest in trying to be helpful.

Math journals, in general, move slowly. The usual advice for a typical math journal is to email the editor after six months without any news.
I would double that length of time for the Annals. As perhaps the most selective math journal anywhere, it can get away with making people wait more.
As to your second question: in my observation, at the very top math journals (Annals/Acta/JAMS/Inventiones/IHES/Duke and a few others) the editorial check takes much longer and involves soliciting a LOT of quick opinions. Only after the board is agreed that the paper is important enough, do they send it out to referees to do a full review, with the goal of checking for correctness and fixing errors.
Other math journals have this same two-step process, of course, but the top journals put much more effort and time into the first step. The vast majority of submissions never make it past this first step, and therefore never get full reviews.

My rule of thumb, for math papers, in the days before the Internet, was: inquire after six months.
